# Сопоставление списков Python

Tags: python

Есть два списка:

```
x = ['Лишь', 'та', '—', 'ошибка', 'что', 'не', 'исправляется']

y = ['ошибка', 'исправляется']
```

Как получить номер порядковых элементов списка x, которые присутствуют в списке y?

```
z = [3, 6]
```

Comment: Что, совсем никаких мыслей на этот счет?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

```
x = ['Лишь', 'та', '—', 'ошибка', 'что', 'не', 'исправляется']
y = ['ошибка', 'исправляется']
z = [index for index, word in enumerate(x) if word in y]
z   #[3, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
z = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] in y:
        z.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Списковым включением](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) и методом [index](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

```
z = [x.index(i) for i in y]
```

Comment: А если будут дубликаты?

Comment: @PavelDurmanov то учтены не будут. Если же учитывать нужно, то стоит использовать ответ Михаила Муругова.

Answer (score -3):

```
y = x.index('ошибка')
z = x.index('исправляется')
print(y, z)
```